# Loop through a directory using TensorFlow Object Detection API

Tags: python, loops, tensorflow, object-detection

I'm trying to loop through a directory containing multiple images and have them analysed for objects using TensorFlow. I'm trying to modify code used to analyse a single image, but can't get it to work. It analyses the first image, displays it and then stops. I was hoping that closing the image/pressing a key on the keyboard would prompt the next one to be analysed and displayed, but it doesn't. The program keeps running (I think), but nothing happens.

I am modifying code from https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10/blob/master/Object_detection_image.py

```
# Name of the directory containing the images to be analysed
DIR_NAME = 'testImages'

# Path to directory containing images to be analysed
PATH_TO_DIR = os.path.join(CWD_PATH, DIR_NAME)

# Iterate through the files to be analysed in the directory
for filename in os.listdir(PATH_TO_DIR):
    if filename.endswith(".jpg"):
        image = cv2.imread(filename)
        image = cv2.resize(image, (800,600))
        image_expanded = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
        (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
            [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
            feed_dict={image_tensor: image_expanded})
        vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
            image,
            np.squeeze(boxes),
            np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
            np.squeeze(scores),
            category_index,
            use_normalized_coordinates=True,
            line_thickness=8,
            min_score_thresh=0.60)
        cv2.imshow('Object detector', image)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Did you press any key on the keyboard? You have `cv2.waitKey(0)` before `cv2.destroyAllWindows()` which means the program waits for your input before destroy the window. Try to press any key and the second image should be shown.

Comment: I was hoping this would be the case but when I press a key it closes the window, my python shell shows '>>>' and my Anaconda Prompt just stays static at where it stopped when the first image is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out one file ended with .jpg and the rest were .JPG

```
if filename.lower().endswith(".jpg"):
```

solved my problem. Oops.